# (N)Multi Level menu datastructure for iteration in ui

Tags: java, database, data-structures, collections

Have a question on how to handle the n level menu in java and further iteration in ui.

Below is the database table data for **MENU**

id  menu_name   parent_id
1   main1       null
2   bank1       1
3   test1       2
4   test2       2
5   test3       2
6   bank2       1
7   test4       6
8   test5       6
9   test6       6

Class Menu is used as a model for the **Menu** table

```
public class Menu {

    private int id;

    private String menuName;

    private int parentId;
}
```

The data retrieved from the database is stored in  `ArrayList<Menu>`

The question is how to represent the n level of menu from the database retrieved as a java object or datastructure which will capture the n level menu and easy iteration for ui and to display multilevel menu navigation list.

**The code needs to be generic for all levels and should en-corporate all levels easily**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here should be dissected into two parts: building menu and accessing menu. Resulting menu is effectively Directed Acyclic Graph or Tree. Each menu item is node in this tree:

```
package my.menu;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MenuNode{
    private MenuNode parent;
    private LinkedList<MenuNode> children;

    private String name;
    private int id;

    public MenuNode(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public MenuNode getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(MenuNode parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void addChild(MenuNode child) {
        children.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }

    public LinkedList<MenuNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}
```

**1. Building menu**

You have some list from database, which you should parse and get object, representing menu. Parser takes line by line, creates new menu node. Then parser should insert this brand new node somewhere in existing tree. Although we can search every time from root using depth-first or breadth-first approach, it would be far more effective to store added nodes in HashMap, especially if our menu structure is large. So, we need MenuTree with parser:

```
package my.menu;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MenuTree{
    private HashMap<Integer, MenuNode> menuMap;

    public void addNode(MenuNode node) {
        MenuNode parent = menuMap.get(node.getParent());
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.addChild(node);
        }        
    }

    public void parse(LinkedList<Menu> input) {
        for (Menu entry : input) {
            MenuNode node = new MenuNode(entry.id, entry.name);
            MenuNode parent = menuMap.get(entry.parentId);
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.addChild(node);
            }
            menuMap.put(node.getId(), node);
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Accessing menu**

Now we can traverse menu either by retrieving `children` LinkedList of `MenuNode` or by adding some method to iterate over `menuMap` in `MenuTree`. It depends on the task we are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

you can save different level of menus in different `arrayList`. Then for each menu check its `parentId` with current `parentId` being iterated. If they match display `subMenu` otherwise pass. This way you can create nested multilevel menus.

or

you can use a map containing `parentMenu` as key and `subMenu` arrayList as value. `Map<ParentMenu, List<String>>`. But that is good solution if you only have two level of menus. More than two levels and it gets clumsy.

Comment: Need a generic solution